# AP Calculus truck mileage problem

Tags: calculus, integration, problem-solving

I apologize in advance for posting a homework problem. Here it is anyway.

> An 18-wheeler traveling at speed *v* mph gets about $4+0.01v$ mpg (miles per gallon) of diesel fuel. If its speed is $80 \dfrac{t+1}{t+2}$ mph at time *t*, then the amount, in gallons, of diesel fuel used during the first 2 hr is approximately: Answer $23.1$.

I can only think of one approach (which doesn't feel right tbh). Find the total number of **miles** traveled during first 2 hours of trip:$$\int_0^2 80 \dfrac{t+1}{t+2}\,dt \approx104.548$$
Then, compute for the total **gallons per mile**, whatever that means.
$$\int_0^2\dfrac{1}{4+0.01(80\frac{t+1}{t+2})}\,dt \approx 0.442$$

Multiplying these two values results in $\sim46.239$ gallons, which is twice the actual answer. What am I missing here?

Comment: Posting a homework problem is not something to apologize for, as long as you do like you've done and write down your own attempts and thoughts about the problem. What we don't like are people who just post the problem and nothing else. Bessides, it's not like we can tell the difference between a homework problem, or a problem you've come acrtoss during self-study, or even a problem you've come up with on your own. So being against homework problems on principle would be difficult.

Comment: @Arthur I'm so relieved to hear that. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$4+0.01v$ is miles per gallon, $\frac1{4+0.01v}$ is gallons per mile, so $v\cdot\frac1{4+0.01v}$ will be gallons per hour, and that's your integrand. You want to calculate
$$\int_0^2\dfrac{80\frac{t+1}{t+2}}{4+0.01\left(80\frac{t+1}{t+2}\right)}\,dt=80\int_0^2\dfrac{t+1}{4.8 t+8.8}\,dt\approx 23.0889.$$

Comment: Nice. Thanks!!!